# how to detect event not get trigger from last two minutes

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am working on live chat for **admin** and **customer** (nodejs+socketio+express). In between chat when customer waiting more than two minutes for admin response I need to show message to customer side **"please try sometime later"**

for example client getting response from this event

```
socket.on('Admin Response',function(msg){

});
```

How to track this event not get trigger from the last two minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is as follows :

```
var timeout=setTimeout(sendMessage,120000);

socket.on('Admin Response',function(msg){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    var timeout=setTimeout(sendMessage,120000);
});
```

For a larger application, I would store last send time (and other information) in an Object that defines the connection.  Have a regular process looks for connections with no activity, and handle appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the the socket event into an [observable](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS), then just use the [.debounce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) operator to only trigger the "please try sometime later" text after 2 minutes of inactivity (untested):

```
var adminResponses = Rx.Observable.fromEventPattern(
    function add (h) {
      socket.on('Admin Response',h);
    }
).debounce(120000); //120000 ms = 2 mins

var subscription = adminResponses.subscribe(
    function(msg) {
         /* show "please try sometime later" text */ 
    });
```